# Get current date, parse string to date and compare the dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime

I have a javascript/jQuery were I get a list from an AJAX call.
I loop through this list and want to split the items into various areas, these areas are based on the date in which the item was inserted into the database.
The date posted/stored in the database is formatted like this

> 2014-03-26 15:36:37

The areas I want to split into is today and the last seven days
I do this with basic if statements like this:

```
if (postedDate == dateNow){
    alert("Today");
}
if (postedDate > dateLastWeek && postedDate < dateNow){
    alert("Last seven days");
}
```

While my date code look like this:

```
var dateDate = new Date();
var dateNow = dateDate.setDate(dateDate.getDate());
var dateLastWeek = dateDate.setDate(dateDate.getDate() - 7);

$.each(data, function (index, value) {
    var postedDate = Date.parse(value.postDate);

    if (postedDate == dateNow){}
    if (postedDate > dateLastWeek && postedDate < dateNow){}
})
```

However the dates becomes these long strings like this: [image]

Were the order is now, lastweek and the post date.

And these does not atleast work with the if statements.

How should I get my dates and format them inorder to compare them correctly?
I mostly just care about splitting them into today and lastweek so hours/minutes/seconds does not really matter.

Thank you.

Comment: have you heard of [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)?

Comment: having them as unix timestamps is the way to go.  In this way, you can compare them like numbers, i.e.  i < 2 === true. Compare them all as unix timestamps.

Comment: @thescientist It does not work though. Unless the if statements are wrong or if the JS is reading my "var postedDate" and similar as strings rather than a timestamp/date/int

Comment: this is probably not good way... but since you mentioned only caring about today and last week... here's a shot in the dark.. http://jsbin.com/yatinegi/1/edit?js,output

Comment: @PsychHalf Yes this will probably work since the database date strings will always be the same, but are you certain that the dates we create will always be correct? i.e when we subtract the seven days will it work if the current day is for example the first day in the month?

Comment: well.. i could write some functions that'll check that too.. but there are already better libraries for that like many people mentioned here.... moment.js :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using momentjs and the date-range plugin:

```
// momentjs     -- http://momentjs.com
// moment-range -- http://gf3.github.io/moment-range/

var data = /* database? */

// setup a date range then check if the date(s) fall within
var dateToday = moment().endOf('day'),
    dateLastWeek = moment().startOf('day').subtract('days', 7),
    dateRange = moment().range(dateLastWeek, dateToday),
    dataFiltered = [];
// iterate over the entries and store those within the range
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    var d = moment(data[i].postDate);
    if (d.isValid()){ // confirm it's a good date
        if (dateRange.contains(d)){ // check if it's in range
            dataFiltered.push(data[i]); // add it
        }
    }
}

// sort the entries
dataFiltered.sort(function(a,b){
    var ad = moment(a.postDate).valueOf(),
        bd = moment(b.postDate).valueOf();
    return ad - bd;
});
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/QT9sE/)

Comment: Yes, this is good. But one thing is missing, how do you check if the postDate is today? your if statement just checks the last seven days while it is missing the if statement for today.

Comment: @HenrikP: You can use `d.endOf('day').isSame(dateToday)`. [exmaple](http://jsfiddle.net/QT9sE/1/). (And my apologies for forgetting it)